# Multiple MX records with different domains - help prove me right

Tags: email-server, mx-record

We use godaddy for our domain hosting. We had an MX record mail.caer.com.mailprotection.com.

Our IT consultant asked me to change it to d264b.ess.barracudanetworks.com.

GoDaddy told me I had to first delete the other one (mailprotection.com) as they do not support two different MX records with different domains.

I deleted the old record and added the new record. The consultant told me I messed everything up? Who is right here?!

Comment: Please tell us more about the final result that's wanted.  MX records are for specifying redundancy; a mail sender should first try the MX with the highest priority, and only try the next priority if the first fails.  (NB: 0 is the *highest* priority; larger numbers are lower priority.)

Answer (score 3):

GoDaddy is wrong - as Bob Brown notes in the comments, MX records are for redundancy, and it is not only legal to have two that point to different servers, it is sometimes necessary. (Backup mail server in case the primary fails or needs to go offline for some reason.) I am very much not surprised by this; I've been steered wrong so many times by GoDaddy TS that when they tell me something, I research before I trust what they've said.

Your consultant is also wrong - having no MX record at all, briefly, will only affect any mail that happens to come in from senders who haven't visited in the past 4 hours or so, while the record is missing. Unless, of course, your consultant hasn't done his job and prepared the new mail server to receive your mail.

You did the best you could with the information you had been given. There's plenty of fault to go around, but I don't see that any of it rests on you.